# Authenticate VNC session with ConsolKit?

Tags: linux, vnc

I have a linux machine running Fedora 16 in a cupboard. It has no screen or keyboard. I connect to it using a combination of vnc and ssh.

Recently, after an update, I have had issues with authentication on the machine.

If I vnc to it, the kde desktop pops up an error dialog every few minutes saying `Authorization failed. Failed to obtain authentication.`

If I plug in a USB drive it fails to mount, Dolphin reports an authentication issue again.

I have had limited success finding the solution. AFAICT, it is an issue with ConsoleKit deeming me to be a non-local user so it prevents authentication.

This is the output from `ck-list-sessions`:

```
$ ck-list-sessions 
Session5:
        unix-user = '1000'
        realname = 'steve'
        seat = 'Seat6'
        session-type = ''
        active = FALSE
        x11-display = ':1'
        x11-display-device = ''
        display-device = ''
        remote-host-name = ''
        is-local = FALSE
        on-since = '2012-09-16T08:07:03.137011Z'
        login-session-id = '1'
```

I have tried to update my `.vnc/xstartup` script to include `ck-launch-session` as follows:

```
$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup 
#!/bin/sh

exec ck-launch-session vncconfig -iconic &
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
OS=`uname -s`
if [ $OS = 'Linux' ]; then
  case "$WINDOWMANAGER" in
    *gnome*)
      if [ -e /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
        PATH=$PATH:/opt/gnome/bin
        export PATH
      fi
      ;;
  esac
fi
if [ -x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
  exec ck-launch-session /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
fi
if [ -f /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
  exec ck-launch-session sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
fi
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
exec ck-launch-session xsetroot -solid grey
exec ck-launch-session xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
exec ck-launch-session twm &
```

This has not helped.

How can I either authenticate myself to ConsoleKit, or trick it into believing I am a local user?

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the way `exec` and `ck-launch-session` work.

1. Every time `ck-launch-session` is used, it creates a *new* session. This means you can't just add it to every single line of your Xstartup – instead you must launch the entire Xstartup script with `ck-launch-session`.

   For example, you could **rename the `xsession` script to `xsession-real`, then run it like this:**

   ```
   exec ck-launch-session ~/.vnc/xsession-real
   ```
2. Every time `exec` is used, it *replaces* the current process with the new one. If the script calls `exec xsetroot`, the rest of the script *will not* be executed. This means you must use it only for the final command.

   (Note: This does not apply when `&` is used. Both `foo &` and `exec foo &` are equivalent; they only replace the child process that `&` creates.)

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   vncconfig -iconic &

   unset SESSION_MANAGER
   unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
   export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
   OS=`uname -s`
   if [ $OS = 'Linux' ]; then
     case "$WINDOWMANAGER" in
       *gnome*)
         if [ -e /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
           PATH=$PATH:/opt/gnome/bin
           export PATH
         fi
         ;;
     esac
   fi

   if [ -x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
       exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
   elif [ -f /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
       exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
   fi

   [ -r ~/.Xresources ] &&
       xrdb ~/.Xresources
   xsetroot -solid grey
   xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
   exec twm
   ```

Comment: thanks for the response, and for the great explanation on how these utilities work. I have done just what you suggested; running `exec ck-launch-session ~/.vnc/xstartup.real &`. If I launch vnc and then `ps -ef` it shows `ck-launch-session` running, but my vnc session is still not authenticated. `ck-list-sessions` still shows `is-local=FALSE` and `active=FALSE`

Comment: `is-local=FALSE` is to be expected, because the session *isn't* local. As for `active=`... I don't even know how ConsoleKit determines activity. I remember it having great trouble with anything other than Xorg or tty...